# How to align the form horizontally in the middle of the div in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label><input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" />
                    <p class="help-block">
                        Example block-level help text here.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                     <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check me out</label>
                </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap.

And I want to align the form in the middle of this `div col-md-12 column`.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Horizontal or Vertical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have two solutions here with the property `display`.

- One with `inline-block`:

  ```
  .col-md-12 column {  
     text-align:center;
  }
  .col-md-12 column form {
     display:inline-block;
  }
  ```
- Two with `table` :

  ```
  .col-md-12 column form {
     display:table;
     margin:auto;
  }
  ```

If you have a fixed `width` for the form you only need to add the `margin:auto`

Answer (score 6):

Demo http://bootply.com/103569

Could use an offset like:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 column">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label><input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" />
                <p class="help-block">
                    Example block-level help text here.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check me out</label>
            </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 column">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label><input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" />
                <p class="help-block">
                    Example block-level help text here.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <label><input type="checkbox" /> Check me out</label>
            </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 1):

Give your form a class

```
<form role="form" class="myForm">
```

and add the following style to it

```
.myForm
{
    width: 480px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

http://bootply.com/103575

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding

```
class="center"
```

to

```
<form role="form">
```

ending up with

```
<form role="form" class="center">
```

and creating the style declaration:

```
.center{margin:0px auto;}
```

keeping in mind that `.center` must have a set width that is less than the width of it's container.

Hope that helps.